# Azure Web App - redirect all traffic from http to https

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, https

We have an Asp.Net Core web application which is running on .Net framework (net452), and hosted in Azure as a Web App.

I'm trying to redirect all http requests to https.

My current understanding is:

1. I can't specify IIS rewrite rules in web.config as the application
   is an Asp.Net Core application
2. I can't use the
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite middleware as of version 2.0.0.0 it
   requires .Net Standard 2.0, and net452 only supports .Net Standard
   1.5.

If the above are correct, what is the best way of doing this?

I'm currently considering writing a small piece of middleware, but feels like there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i really doubt for point 1. 
because it is an IIS setting. 
anything under `<system.webServer>` is only related to IIS not the tech you are using, even with PHP/Java/pureHtml applications, you can still use that section to add rewrite rules. the rewrite will happen before your requests reach your application. BUT for azure apps, you mean need to enable ARR, it used to have some issue with rewrite rules, but now it should be fine because recently i just set some rules for a PHP application in a new Azure app

Comment: We are using IIS Rewrite rules in the web.config which is working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an App Service [custom extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-web-sites-extensions/).

For example, there's an extension that forces traffic to go via HTTPS, described in this [post](https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/12/azure-app-service-force-redirect-from-http-to-https-the-easy-way/).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#redirect-http-traffic-to-https) redirects all http traffic to https. It also makes sure that the site warmup request gets through, which makes things work correctly in site swap and Always On scenarios.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-
Transform">
<location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" 
xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
<system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  <applicationInitialization xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <add initializationPage="/"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
  </applicationInitialization>

  <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
 appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>    
</system.webServer>
```